# Decimal dot and thousands separator used both in input type number

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

How is possible to use both decimal dot and thousands separator in `input type="number"`, more specifically within AngularJS model? For example, the numeric value the user be able to write, should look like this: `3,597.50`. Also, I have to make a check if the entered data is a number or a string which I make with isNaN(). 
I tried `someNumber.toFixed(2)`, where `someNumber` is a variable, containing the number which the user has entered but it doesn't work.

Comment: share your code please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried https://github.com/aguirrel/ng-currency ?

Its pretty decent...

Comment: I think it will do the job. Thank you.